# Static equilibrium of forces A-Level question.

Tags: vectors

Can anyone help clarify my thinking regarding this question please?

A particle rests on a rough plane inclined at $\theta$ to the horizontal.
The coefficient of friction between the particle and the plane is $\mu$.
When the weight of the particle is W, a horizontal force of magnitude P just prevents the particle from slipping down the place.
If however a force of magnitude 2P acts parallel to the place, the particle is on the point of slipping up the place.
The same force acting on a particle of weight 2W just prevents it from slipping down the same plane. Find the values of $\theta$ and $\mu$, and express P in terms of W.

I have answered the question and agree with the answers supplied in the text book of origin.

I call the three cases above 1, 2 and 3, In each case I derive two equations by equating the forces parallel to the plane and the forces perpendicular to the plane respectively. I get the following equations:

**Case 1**

$\mu R + P \cos\theta = W \sin \theta$

$R=P \sin \theta + W \cos\theta$

**Case 2**

$2P = \mu R + W \sin\theta$

$R = W\cos \theta$

**Case 3**

$\mu R + 2P = 2W \sin \theta$

$R = 2W \cos \theta$

In order of appearance call these equations 1 to 6.

In solving the question and obtaining the answers:

$\theta = 60 ^{\circ}$

$\mu = \frac{\sqrt{3}}{3}$

$P = \frac{\sqrt{3}}{3} W$

I used all but equation (2). However, if one looks at equation (2) and equation (4) one would conclude that $P \sin \theta = 0$ which is not that case as regards the book's answers for those values.

Could anyone help explain my error please?

Thanks,
Mitch.

Comment: $R$ is not a fixed size, but depends on each situation. You could have called it $R_1$, $R_2$ and $R_3$ in each case, to avoid confusion.

Comment: Of course, I see now. Thanks.